# Comparing cells using match in vba

Tags: vba, excel, match

I am trying to compare two columns of cells in vba using the match function.  I am comparing the second column against values in the first and copying and pasting the values that aren't found to another column.  I am doing the same with the second against the first as well.  For some reason when I try to run this it says that it cannot get the match property of the worksheet function class and I am really confused as to why I am receiving this error.  I have pasted the code below. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
Set PrevMonth = Sheet13.Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set currMonth = Sheet13.Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Count = 2

For i = 2 To PrevMonth.Rows.Count
match = Application.WorksheetFunction.match(Cells(i, 1), currMonth, 0)
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(match) = True Then
Sheet13.Cells(i, 1).Cut
Sheet13.Cells(Count, 3).Paste
Count = Count + 1
End If
Next i

For i = 2 To currMonth.Rows.Count
match = WorksheetFunction.match(Cells(i, 1), PrevMonth, 0)
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(match) = True Then
Sheet13.Cells(i, 1).Cut
Sheet13.Cells(Count, 4).Paste
Count = Count + 1
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using

```
Application.Match(Cells(i, 1), currMonth, 0)
```

I know this should have been a comment...but I'm unable to comment as I'm below 50 Rep...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the "cannot get 'X' property of the worksheet function class" error is indicative that a poor argument has been passed to the worksheet function itself.  In your case the arguments are: Cells(i, 1), currMonth.  This likely means one of those ranges are inaccessible.  If I had to guess, you want to be passing sheet13.cells(i,1).  I'd recommend a 'with sheet13' statement for this whole segment of code.  WorksheetFunction.Match in particular will throw that error if a match can't be found (VB doesn't work with the #N/A return value).  Using a WorksheetFunction.CountIf > 0 can ensure there is a viable match within the range.

Also, Range("A2").End(xlDown) will result in the last cell of the column if there is no data after A2.  This is generally unfavorable behavior.